# Spring JPA repository interface and default methods use case

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, default-method

I am currently wondering whether a particular use case could be elegantly addressed by using a default interface method inside a JPA repository.

Suppose we have the following entity and supporting types:

```
public enum Status {
   STATUS_1,
   STATUS_2,
   STATUS_3
}
 

@Entity
@Getter // from lombok
@Setter // from lombok
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;
}
```

I need to be able to query a list of `SomeEntity` based on combination of `Status` enumeration values.

With Spring JPA, its respective repository could look like this:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("select s.id, ... from SomeEntity s where s.status in (:statuses)")
    List<SomeEntity> getByStatuses(@Param("statuses") List<Status> statuses);
}
```

The particular combinations of statuses that must be passed, however is very much dependent on the domain of `SomeEntity`, and I'd like to "bake-in"  those statuses in the repository call. Why in the repository -- currently the same repository is used from multiple services, and `SomeEntity` is updated as part of transactions dealing with other entities updated together according to the service's specifics. The particular `getByStatuses` calls are the same for all services, and we have duplicated code fragments looking roughly like this:

```
List<Status> statuses = Arrays.asList(Status.STATUS_1, Status.STATUS_3);
List<SomeEntity> entities = someRepository.getByStatuses(statueses);
....
```

I was wondering if I could extract the above fragment in a default method inside the repository and change my services to use that method instead:

```
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("select s.id, ... from SomeEntity s where s.status in (:statuses)")
    List<SomeEntity> getByStatuses(@Param("statuses") List<Status> statuses);

    default List<SomeEntity> getByRelevantStatuses() {
        List<Status> relevantStatuses = Arrays.asList(Status.STATUS_1, Status.STATUS_3);
        return this.getByStatuses(relevantStatuses);
    }
}
```

My concerns are the "magic" behind the scenes which Spring will do, could it cause issues with an approach like the above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the default interface method usage in the described scenario is working. I tried it and so far I have not seen any problems.

I'll still be happy to know if there are things to worry about, and if I find anything useful myself, I will update this post.