# Kotlin extension function not calling overridden function in hibernate/jpa

Tags: function, kotlin, jpa

There is a pretty useful extension function for spring boot jpa in kotlin that is defined like this:

```kotlin
fun <T, ID> CrudRepository<T, ID>.findByIdOrNull(id: ID): T? = findById(id).orElse(null)
```

In my repository, I've overridden the `findById` method like so:

```kotlin
@Query("from Foo v where v.id = :id and v.deletedAt is null")
override fun findById(id: UUID): Optional<Foo>
```

I'd expect this overridden function to be called when using `findByIdOrNull`().
So I tested in the debugger:

```
fooRepository.findById(foo.id)
```

The result was Optional.empty as expected

Now I tested using the same entity, without changing anything else:

```
fooRepository.findByIdOrNull(foo.id)
```

and a result could be found. The deletedAt variable was set and therefore it should not have been found.

Using a debugger, I could also verify that my own `findById` with custom query that I defined earler is not (!) called!

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What happens if you rewrite your extension function as an ordinary function (taking the `CrudRepository` as the first param instead of a receiver)?  (BTW, you have _overridden_ the repository method, not ‘overwritten’ it.)

Comment: Hi @gidds, thanks for the hint ;) i'll correct that.

Comment: I tried your tip using this custom function: `fun <T, ID> findByIdOrNullCustom(repository: CrudRepository<T, ID>, id: ID): T? where ID : Any = repository.findById(id).orElse(null)`.
Same behaviour: I get a result and the overridden function is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the non-execution behaviour you are seeing is to do with the way Spring creates a run-time implementation of the database access code by using a proxy.  I don't have proof of this, but it is my hunch.

If you have used `@Trasactional` or `@Cacheable`, you can get caught out trying to use a transaction or cache in the very same class that those annotations are declared (see [Spring cache @Cacheable method ignored when called from within the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116107/1847378))

So how to fix it?  I suspect you will struggle with the Kotlin Extension function for this reason, so you could try to embed an alternate copy of the `findByIdOrNull` in the Repository interface.

I had a quick go at that, but then you walk into another problem that even if you code a non-abstract method in the Repository interface, Spring ignores the body and raises a `QueryCreationException` because if cannot work out how to form a query:

```
Could not create query for public abstract Foo FooRepository.findByIdOrNull(UUID); Reason: No property 'null' found for type Foo
```

There doesn't seem to be an "@IgnoreQueryParsing" annotation, so the typical work in this area is where you see people creating concrete classes for complex queries alongside the autogenerated methods (see [Spring JPA: How to disable query creation for certain method : CustomImpl class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71748142/1847378) ), but *that* technique cannot see the autogenerated methods.

The next approach is a compile parameter suggested by @bruno-medeiros in
[Spring JPA: How to disable query creation for certain method : jvm-default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76507180/1847378), but now you are changing things that alter compilation for your whole application.

We're now a long way from where we started - I think this is overkill!  I suggest you go back to this much simpler approach:

```
findById(id).getOrNull()
```

Interesting question nonetheless!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is more or less what we also came up with after talking to (a lot!!) or collegues. Gave us a pretty interesting insight of how spring/jpa/hibernate actually handles things and where extension functions jump in.